# How to truncate the MySQL performance_schema in Google Cloud SQL without restarting DB instance?

Tags: google-cloud-sql

According to the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sys-ps-truncate-all-tables.html) we can truncate the `performance_schema` with the help of the following call:

```
CALL sys.ps_truncate_all_tables(FALSE);
```

Internally this procedure is coded like [follows](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/a246bad76b9271cb4333634e954040a970222e0a/scripts/sys_schema/procedures/ps_truncate_all_tables.sql). It actually executes `TRUNCATE TABLE` statements against a list of tables obtained with the masks `'%summary%'` and `'%history%'`.

The problem is that **root** user isn't able to perform the `TRUNCATE TABLE` statement on the `performance_schema` database in Google Cloud SQL due to [superuser restrictions](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/users#:%7E:text=access%20your%20instance.-,Superuser%20restrictions,to%20users%20with%20superuser%20attributes.).

```
mysql> truncate table performance_schema.events_statements_summary_by_digest ; 
ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) 
the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
```

I didn't find any Cloud SQL Admin API or other method to do this.

Any advice, how to reset the MySQL `performance_schema` in Google Cloud SQL without restarting DB instance.

UPD. I have found that it does not work for MySQL 5.7 but works well for MySQL 8.0 in Google Cloud SQL. So that if you can migrate your Google DB instance to MySQL 8.0 it would be workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there are no workarounds other than restarting the DB instances. And there is already a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/128898008) raised for the same. You can +1 and CC yourself in the request to show interest in this being implemented and receive an email in case there are any updates.

In case you want to use `performance_schema` for database sql query analysis, as an alternative, you can use [`CloudSql Query Insights`](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/using-query-insights). Query insights helps you detect, diagnose, and prevent query performance problems for `Cloud SQL` databases. It supports intuitive monitoring and provides diagnostic information that helps you go beyond detection to identify the root cause of performance problems.

Or you can contact [Google support](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/getting-support), Product Team may offer up the stored procedure solution.